# How to add a URL parameter to {@url} for actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE?

Tags: android, app-actions, google-assistant

[Google's official document](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents/common/open-app-feature) says actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE supports only urlTemplate set to "{@url}" with no fallback fulfillment.

The following is their sample code for actions.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <!-- This is a sample actions.xml -->
  <actions>
    <action intentName="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">
      <!-- Use url from inventory match for deep link fulfillment -->
      <fulfillment urlTemplate="{@url}" />


      <!-- Define parameters with inventories here -->
      <parameter name="feature">
        <entity-set-reference entitySetId="featureParamEntitySet"/>
      </parameter>
    </action>

    <entity-set entitySetId="featureParamEntitySet">
      <!-- Provide a URL per entity -->
      <entity url="myapp://deeplink/one" name="featureParam_one" alternateName="@array/featureParam_one_synonyms"/>
      <entity url="myapp://deeplink/two" name="featureParam_two" alternateName="@array/featureParam_two_synonyms"/>
    </entity-set>
  </actions>
```

It means that I can say "Open featureParam_two from myapp" to start the app with deep link  "myapp://deeplink/two".

If the app has user-defined names such as "front door", "first bathroom", how can those names be passed to the app to allow users to say "open front door from myapp" or "open first bathroom from myapp" to open the app and the corresponding feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can use alternate names/synonyms to define those features.

For example, you can use the following definition:

```
<entity-set entitySetId="featureParamEntitySet">
      <!-- Provide a URL per entity -->
      <entity url="myapp://deeplink/front-door" name="front door" alternateName="@array/front-door-synonyms"/>
      <entity url="myapp://deeplink/two" name="first bathrooms" alternateName="@array/first-bathroom-synonyms"/>
</entity-set>
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help.  I am not sure if I was clear about what I need.  I meant users can use arbitrary names that I can never exhaust.  In other words, they may use literally hundreds of thousands of different names.

Comment: Got it. Your assumption is correct. Currently, OPEN_APP_FEATURE BII doesn't support fallback fulfillment. Please recheck the docs for support of this feature.

Comment: Please try this again. Fallback fulfillment is now supported.

Comment: The support does tell me how to add a URL parameter.  That is the core issue.